# RxJs indefinite observable calls

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

I need to retrieve indefinite amount of data from the server. That should go in the following way:

1. send initial request
2. retrieve a part of data and tell the server that everything is OK an I can get some more data
3. repeat steps 2 and 3 until I receive a specific value that means that there is no more data

How can I do this using observables?

For now I can only think of recursive observable calls from withing some function like.

```
const send = execSend() {
    this.send(message).subscribe(resp => {
        if (resp === 'end') {
            subscriber.next(byteArr.join(''));
            console.log('finished');
            subscriber.complete();
        } else {
            byteArr.push(resp);
            execSend();
        }
    });
}();
```

Comment: Do you want to send the same request everytime?

Comment: Yes. It's just to tell the server that I got my value and ready for the next one. To be more precise all this is for retrieving a huge data by pieces to combine it all when everything is received. Since a WebSocket is being used we are limited to the data size limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should replicate your idea: 1 event emitted before completition.

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { expand, takeWhile, reduce } from 'rxjs/operators';

let count = 0;
const FINISH = "finished";
const limit = 5;
const send$ = () => of(count++ < limit ? "sent" : FINISH);

const expander$ = send$().pipe(
  expand(resp => send$()),
  takeWhile(resp => resp !== FINISH),
  reduce((acc, val) => acc ? acc + val : val, null)
);

const subscribe = expander$.subscribe(console.log);
```

You can see it working in [this blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-t6rzid?file=index.ts)

Comment: Won't this crash if my observable (send) completes right after passing a value?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: My observable emits value and completes subscription right after that.

Comment: The example one does the same, `send$` creates an observable that emits one value and completes...

Comment: Thank you I will try. Why is `send$` a function? Not just `send$ = of(...)`

Comment: Good question! Two reasons: simulate the creation of a new request and ensure that the counter goes up. If you refactor send$ to be a reference, the sample will overflow as the `count++` expression will be evaluated during the invocation of `of`, ergo once. You caught me off-guard there, took me some mins to realize what consequences that could have.

Comment: @Sergey consider to accept this answer if it solved your issue, so that your question can be preserved.

Comment: I know. I haven't tried anything to say that that solved my problem. I need some time.

Comment: @Sergey any luck?

Comment: Not yet. Have some job to do before testing it (need an API first)

Comment: Finally I gave it a shot. Works well except for that now I need to not to respond to last message. Sorry for such latency.

Comment: With modification `expand(resp => resp !== 'finish' ? this.send('ok') : empty()),` works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you can try this pattern

```
exec=()=>http.get(....) 

exec().pipe(
  expand((resp)=>exec()),
  takeWhile(resp=>resp !== 'end'),
  scan((acc,curr)=>acc.concat(curr),[])
).subscribe()
```

Answer (score -1):

something like this:

```
let todo = true;
interval(100).pipe(
    takeWhile(()=>todo),
    concatMap(()=>getStuff())
).subscribe(data => {
  todo = !isFinished(data);
});
```